# PHP 特定のタグを消したい　（キーとなる言葉を複数）

Tags: php

```
    foreach ($xpath->query('//a[contains(@href,"yahoo")]') as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);//そのタグを消す
    }
```

PHP　HTMLパースの話です。
上記で　a タグの　href要素に　yahoo　を含むものが、そのタグ毎削除できるのはわかります

同様に複数削除したいキーワードがある場合に
$varArr にキーワードを含む配列を作り、次のように書きましたが
Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in　（そのPHPの場所）～～
のエラーがでます。
エラーの内容を調べると　"' を使ってはいけない、らしいですが
String型の配列を作る場合、" ' は必要になりますよね？どう回避するのでしょうか。

できれば削除すべきキーワードは１つの変数に保持したいため
逐一　最初の行のプログラムをかき回すのでなく、for文等で処理したいと考えます。

どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

```
$varArr = array("yahoo","google","livedoor","keyword3");
for($i=0;count($varArr)>$i;$i++){
    foreach ($xpath->query('//a[contains(@href,$varArr[$i])]') as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$xpath->query('//a[contains(@href,$varArr[$i])]'`
の部分を
`$xpath->query("//a[contains(@href,$varArr[$i])]"`
のように変更します。
これは、`' '`と`" "`で埋め込み変数の展開が異なるためです。
（`' '`の場合は展開されない）

以下を試してみるとわかりやすいと思いいます。

```
$varArr = array("yahoo","google","livedoor","keyword3");
for($i=0;count($varArr)>$i;$i++){
    print '$varArr[$i]' . "$varArr[$i]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XPathに直接変数を埋め込まない方がいいよ。

```
$varArr = array("yahoo","google","livedoor","keyword3");
foreach ($xpath->query('//a') as $node) {
    foreach ($varArr as $v) {
        if (strpos($node->getAttribute('href'), $v) === false) {
            continue;
        }
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node); //そのタグを消す
        break;
    }
}
```